# Sequelize adding extra quotes to LIKE

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

It is a conditional query. So that's why the code begins with:

```
var where = [];
```

Then I always put the ID for searching:

```
where.push({myId: myId});
```

I then check if conditions are met and in that case add a LIKE:

```
if(req.query.search !== undefined && req.query.search != ''){
where.push({name: {$like: req.query.search}});
}
```

When looking at the generated query I see:

```
SELECT "id", "name" FROM "MyTable" WHERE ("MyTable"."myId" = 1 AND  "MyTable"."name" LIKE '''%''ABCD''%''');
```

As you can see a lot of quotes are added.

If I manually remove all the quotes but the first and the last, then the query executes well.

Why is sequelize adding all those quotes? Am I using the LIKE operator in the wrong way?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I faced this case recently and didn't found any issues related. Both `like` and `$like` didn't work in my case. And after some trials this works:

```
model.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('columnName'), {
    like: `%${string}%`,
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By bad. I changed $like with like and all the quotes disappeared.